# Properties of the limit of a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I have this series $$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^n 10^{-k^2}.$$

I have the series and the question is. Which of the following does the limit belong to?

A) doesn't exist

B) $[-1,0)$

C) $\{0,1,2\}$

D) $\Bbb Q$

E) $\Bbb R\setminus \Bbb Q$

I can't figure out the answer is E. Can someone help out? I will appreciate it a lot. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you familiar with any convergence tests? Otherwise, maybe you can see that the sum is just a base 10 expansion and is $1.100100001\ldots$, where the $1$'s occur whenever their position is a perfect square.

Comment: Hint: A real number is rational iff it has a repeating dec...

Comment: Oh! Know I get it. I was forgetting to add the "1" when I wrote the series on paper. Silly me. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test):

$$\lim_{k \to +\infty}\sqrt[k]{10^{-k^2}} = \lim_{k \to +\infty}(10^{-k^2})^{\frac{1}{k}} = \lim_{k \to +\infty}10^{-k} = 0.$$

Since this limit goes to $$\lim_{k \to +\infty}\sqrt[k]{10^{-k^2}} = 0 < 1$$
then your series converges. We can exclude option $A$.

Surely the series converges to a positive number (indeed, you are summing  up positive numbers $10^{-k^2}$). So, we exclude option $B$.

As noticed by Alex R., the number you obtain has the form $
1.100100001...$, so it can't be integer. We need to exclude option $C$.

Following the Shalop hint, the number can't be rational, and we exclude $D$.

Finally, the solution is $E$.